# Maven does not copy spring jars in WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a multi module maven project : `parent-proj` which two submodules : `child-dao-proj` and `child-web-proj`. `child-dao-proj` is a  maven java project while `child-web-proj` is a web project. 
In the pom parent project, I declared all the required dependencies needed by both :

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>fr.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-proj</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>child-dao-proj</module>
    <module>child-web-proj</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Jars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Mysql connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.180</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I put all needed dependencies for the persistence jars (hibernate, spring-orm, spring-data, etc) in `child-dao-proj` and all the web jars (spring-mvc, spring-web, etc) for `child-web-proj`.

When I run mvn clean install and deploy the web project in Tomcat, I am stuck with this error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`.

After searching, it seems that the spring jars are not copied in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

[EDIT] Here the pom for the web project :

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent-proj</artifactId>
    <groupId>fr.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>child-web-proj</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.myproject.dao</groupId>
        <artifactId>child-dao-proj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I forgot to mention that I am working with Intellij.

[EDIT] Here is the output of `mvn dependency:tree` :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building child-web-proj Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ child-web-proj ---
[INFO] fr.myproject:child-web-proj:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- fr.myproject:child-dao-proj:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.6.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.8.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.31:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.180:test
[INFO] \- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: try manually filling in `${spring.version}`. Of course the children do not have a `<version>`.

Comment: Yes, I do not include the version in the child dependencies

Comment: Can you please show us the pom from which you build the war file?

Comment: can you provide the pom for child-web-proj

Comment: Show us your child pom. Put the parts with `<dependencies/>` as well. If your dependencies are with `<scope>provided</scope>`, they will not get included in the `war` file. Also, paste the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: During packaging the war module will resolve all runtime scoped dependencies and place them in WEB-INF/lib as you would expect. You do not say anything about the other dependencies, so I must assume they are present. In order to debug what maven does, you can use the `-X` flag. The output is verbose, but you can see what the packaging plugin resolves as web libraries.

Comment: In my opinion the strange thing is : **child-web-proj is a web project**. Can you share with us the web project structure and how you run install and deploy on a non maven project?

Comment: The project structure is simple. parent-proj is a empty maven project containing a pom.xml. This project contains 2 sub projects : child-web-proj and child-dao-proj.

Comment: I already shared the pom.xml of the web module

Comment: If your child-dao-proj is a "normal" Java-jar-project it's dependencies will usually not be copied if you build it with maven. There are multiple ways to resolve this, e.g. use maven-assembly-plugin to create a "jar-with-dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to manage your situation:

You can import the spring-framework-bom in the dependencyManagement of your parent  section to ensure that all spring dependencies are at the same version.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and in yout war project you can declare the dependencie in this way:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

in this way you can avoid to repeat spring version to each spring's module